# SqlAlchemy add hybrid property that is a sum of a datetime and a numeric field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to calculate a field combining two existing fields in a SQLAlchemy Model, and use it in the query parameters.

I have a model like this:

```py
    class Booking(BaseORMModel):
      start: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True))
      minutes: duration_minutes: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Numeric)
```

I want to dynamically calculate the end as the sum of `start` and `minutes`. This is my attempt:

```py
    class Booking(BaseORMModel):
      ...
      @hybrid_property
    def ended_at(self):
        return self.scheduled_at + timedelta(minutes=self.duration_minutes)

    @ended_at.expression
    def ended_at(cls):
        duration_interval = func.cast(concat(cls.duration_minutes, ' MINUTES'), INTERVAL)
        ended_at = func.sum(cls.scheduled_at + duration_interval)
        return ended_at
```

This is my query

```py
query = query.where(Booking.ended_at < now)
```

This is what I get:

```bash
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg.errors.UndefinedFunction) function sum(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
@ended_at.expression  # type: ignore[no-redef]
    def ended_at(cls):
        casted_duration = func.cast(cls.duration_minutes, Integer)
        # make_interval params: (years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
        interval = func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, casted_duration)
        ended_at = cls.scheduled_at + interval
        return ended_at
```